# High beams work, low beams do not

Tags: subaru, headlight

Working on fixing up a 2002 Subaru forester. High beams work fine but the low beams are out. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you actually tried, there's a few possibilities here.

Answer (score 3):

Check the bulbs, relay for low beam and the fuses for low beams - usually there are fuses per side for headlights.

Comment: I've replaced the bulbs and fuses today, still having issues so I'm going to guess it's the relay.

Answer (score 0):

the low beam fuses are blown. you will have to replace it.